# Java. Поиск в Массиве, по набранному тексту

Tags: java, строки, поиск, arraylist, фильтр

Можно ли реализовать поиск в массиве по набранному в EditText тексту?
В адаптаре у меня есть фильтр, которы находит набранный текст в ArrayList, создает новый ArrayList и вставляет туда данные

```
public void filter(String query) {
    mFilteredCheeses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String cheese : mDefaultCheeses) {
        if(cheese.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
            mFilteredCheeses.add(cheese);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Можно ли тоже самое сделать, но с массивом String[]

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Зачем вам это?\

Comment: Ну если в итоге надо получить массив, то можно попробовать воспользоваться метом toArray у списка c параметром что-то вроде `new String[mFilteredCheeses.size()]`

Comment: ЮрийСПб Я все хочу разобраться, с добавлением в избранное и с фильтрам. 
Я уже создал уже два адаптара, первый для избранного, второй для фильтра. Хочу все это объединить вот и эксперементирую с кодом, думаю может лучше заполнять список с массива. Незнаю уже замучился с этим кодом.
Вроде элементарная задача, которая почти в каждой второй программе встречается и немогу никак найти нормальное решение

Comment: @Artsait, если вы не знаете точно чем массив в к-л случае будет лучше списка, то всегда используйте список. Массив вам тут ничем не поможет